# How does one place predefined circles on a grid so that they do not overlap?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, graph, geometry

I am making an app where predefined circles will be drawn on the screen. Before placing the circle, I know how big the radius is. I am struggling to place the circles so that they do not overlap. In the simplest terms, I need a function that takes in radiuses and returns a list of (x, y) coordinates where they do not overlap. It would also be helpful to be able to prioritize some circles towards the origin of the plane.

I have found algorithms that can place random circles with ought them overlapping, but struggle to apply them to predefined circles in an efficient way.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is related to [Circle packing with unequal circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Unequal_circles) which has some very hard sub-problems. I would be amazed if you found an algorithm that always gives a correct answer. Would an algorithm that usually gives good answers be good enough for your purpose? (I have no good ideas even for that kind of answer.)

Comment: Your title says "on a grid" but not the body.

Comment: What percentage of the screen will be covered by the circles? Below a certain threshold, the problem is trivial, above another threshold, the problem is impossible. Somewhere between those thresholds, an evolutionary algorithm might be effective. A greedy algorithm which places the circles from the largest to the smallest might also work.

Comment: More details would be helpful, such as the range of the radiuses, the number of circles (and size frequency), the size of the plane, priorities such as can and which circles may be discarded, preferred aesthetics/positioning, etc.